# Rails API SSL issue : 'no suitable key share' when using https with ReactJS client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ssl-certificate, axios, rails-api

I need to use https protocol for development purposes. I have a Rails API working with a ReactJS client.

**Client side**

I set my https on client side within my package json, like following :

*package.json*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "HTTPS=true PORT=3001 react-scripts start"
  }
}
```

Then, I configured my axios instance :

*axiosClient.js*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import https from 'https';
// Those are the same certificates I will later use on server side
import crt from 'path/to/ssl/localhost.crt.pem';
import key from 'path/to/ssl/localhost.key.pem';

const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  cert: crt,
  key: key
});

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL,
  httpsAgent,
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true, // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

export default axiosClient;
```

**Server side**

I generated the self-signed certificate from terminal, then placed it in a `ssl` folder in my config folder.

```
project_folder
  |- config
    |- ssl
      |- localhost.crt
      |- localhost.key
```

Then, I add the following line to my `development.rb` file :

*development.rb*

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

**My error**

I searched and tried many things, but can't get rid off the following error on my client side :

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

And on my server side console:

```
2019-07-29 12:17:04 +0200: SSL error, peer: 127.0.0.1, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:141F7065:SSL routines:final_key_share:no suitable key share - 337604709>
```

How can I get rid off this ? I use the exact same certificates in both ReactJS and Rails.

**EDIT**

Here is my environment file in React :

*.env.development.local*

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL="https://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

The calls to server are made with https protocol, which I checked in console.